# Is it possible to include functions from .c file without compiling it?

Tags: c, gcc, include

I am restricted by very specific (and rather senseless...) filing system and I can't create header files or split existing files into files holding only functions and only execution calls. I can only create .c files that can be executed and have some sort of output.

A lot of code can be reused but I am being forced to copy some functions from file to file.

Is it possible to cure this mess by including but not compiling one or more file or omitting some functions in the included files? Maybe adding some debugging into the mix can allow to compile only part of included files?

Comment: Can you show us what you mean?  You can include .c/.cpp files from another .c/.cpp file, but it is not considered good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the shared code like this, so that it can compile on it's own and at the same time you can include it from other .c files without getting duplicate main functions:

```
 // shared.c
 #ifndef SHARED_C
 #define SHARED_C

 #if __INCLUDE_LEVEL__ == 0
 #    include <stdio.h>
 #    include <stdlib.h>
 int main() { 
     fprintf(stderr, "shared file, not to run!\n");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }

 #endif


 int shared_func() { return 1; }

 #endif
```

And use it from other files

```
#include "shared.c"
int x = shared_func();
```

Comment: Missing a second `#endif` and I noticed that functions can only be defined after main in between `#endif` otherwise some includes get uppset

Comment: @PovilasSid oh, good catch, although I don't immediately see why the placement of main would matter

Comment: It was weird for me to but then I tried using open() I started getting
`/usr/include/fcntl.h: At top level:
/usr/include/fcntl.h:110:12: error: conflicting types for āopenā`
And changing the place fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the pre-processor?  Something like:

```
// this is file1.c
int Foo(int bar);
#ifndef HEADERS
int Foo(int bar)
{
    return 42;
}
#endif
```

and

```
// this is file2.c
#define HEADERS
#include "file1.c"

Foo(42);
```